# JToken does not contain a definition for 'length

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have a JSON data in a file with .json extension. I grabbing and reading the JSON from the file. My problem is how do I check if the `payment` array has any children.

I have tried `o2["payment"].length()` but it's giving me an error

> 'JToken' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension
>   method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'JToken' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

```
{
    "bank_name": "MyBank",
    "payment": [
        {
            "ssn": "123456789",
            "description": "Payment for income tax for 2015",
            "amount": "55.00"
        },
        {
            "ssn": "123456789",
            "description": "Payment for income tax for 2016",
            "amount": "95.10"
        },
        {
            "ssn": "123456789",
            "description": "Payment for income tax for 2017",
            "amount": "35.03"
        }
    ]
}




public ActionResult ReadFile()
{

    var Path = "C:\\Payment";
    var PendingPath = Path + "\\Pending";

    string[] FilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@PendingPath, "*.json");
    foreach ( var CurrentFile in FilePaths )
    {
        using (StreamReader file = System.IO.File.OpenText(CurrentFile))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            var bank_name = o2["bank_name"];
            if ( o2["payment"].length() ) //Check here if payment has any children
            {

            }
        }
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Cast `o2["payment"]` as a JArray

Comment: @Sxntk I tried casting like `(JArray) o2["payment"]`. I get an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: The condition should be ((JArray)o2["payment"]).Count > 0

Comment: @Sxntk great it works. Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the methods of arrays you should cast the object:

```
if (((JArray)o2["payment"]).Count > 0)
{
    // Logic...
}
```